# Selenium Webdriver | Python (Tumblr) : Cannot access element ID after posting

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, eclipse

I'm trying to create a test case for Tumblr (currently in the process of learning automation) and I'm stuck on trying to access the drafts page. So here's what's happening - after I post an image as draft and try to access "Drafts" and delete them, below is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\Pytest\python1\PySel.py", 
line 93, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_id('account_button').click()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in 
click self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 501, in 
_execute return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 308, in 
execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, 
in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Element <div class="tab iconic tab_nav_account " id="account_button">...
</div> is not clickable at point (924, 28). Other element would receive the 
click: <div class="v-center-inner">...</div>
(Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 
(e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 
x86_64)
```

I've tried page refresh -which causes a prompt if I want to terminate the post which I find weird as to why it does not wait to post first before it refreshes itself (see attached image)[image]

and implicit wait but that doesn't seem to do anything. The code `driver.find_element_by_id('account_button').click()` works just fine at the beginning but suddenly won't run after posting draft. I think this has something to do with switching window maybe? Another thing is how do I locate the window name for the posting section?

(see image attached)
[image: Is this considered a window where you can call for switching windows?]

**This is my complete code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
import os

user = ""
pwd = ""
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.tumblr.com/login")
assert "Tumblr" in driver.title

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("signup_determine_email")
elem.send_keys("email")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("signup_password")
elem.send_keys("password")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.find_element_by_id('account_button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/settings']").click()
assert "Account" in driver.title
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.back()

driver.find_element_by_class_name('compose-button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='post-type-icon icon-text']").click()

driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".post-form--save-button .dropdown-area").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='editor editor-richtext']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='editor editor-plaintext']").send_keys("This is a Test Title")<br>
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='editor editor-richtext']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='control add-image']").click()
os.system(r'"C:/Users/pmevangelista/Desktop/AutoIt/FileUpload.exe"')<br>
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='editor editor-richtext']").send_keys("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
driver.implicitly_wait(60)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".post-form--save-button .button-area").click()
driver.refresh()
driver.find_element_by_id('account_button').click()<br>
```

Comment: Did you find solution.
Because I am stuck in same problem 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message

```
Element <div class="tab iconic tab_nav_account " id="account_button">...</div>
is not clickable at point (924, 28). Other element would receive the click:
<div class="v-center-inner">...</div>
```

shows, that your test case order to click on the element, which is present and displayed, but it is not clickable because is covered by another object as a popup, iframe or a tooltip.

So before you click on the object, you should handle the iframe/popup/tooltip and make them close/wait for them to hide.